# How to change text in Woo-commerce - Coinbase Commerce

Tags: woocommerce, edit, coinbase-api

I want to change this text I did not know where to change
Woo-commerce - payment gateway coinbase commerce

In this image the word in red circle

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're talking about [Commerce Coinbase For WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/commerce-coinbase-for-woocommerce/). To update that, you'll need to edit the file `coinbase-gateway-for-woocommerce.php` on line 262 found in `wp-content/plugins/`. Ideally this should be removed by the plugin authors as it's odd that it has the word "WooCommerce" in it. I recommend reaching out to the plugin author on that as well since an update would erase your changes.